# Use Google Translate library without composer

Tags: php, google-translate

I am trying to integrate Google Translate library in a legacy application which does not use composer, and I have downloaded the source code folder "google-cloud-php-master".

Can anyone point me how to use the library without composer?

When I try to execute the below code

```
use Google\Cloud\Translate\TranslateClient;

$translate = new TranslateClient();
```

I am getting the below error. Any help would be appreciate.

> Fatal error: Class 'Google\Cloud\Translate\TranslateClient' not found

Comment: You should probably implement your own autoloader, which sounds more complicated than it actually is. [The PHP docs explain it pretty well](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Comment: There's no problem to add composer in a legacy project. You could copy the vendor folder from another project. After all, for most of all projects, composer just do a rough copy into your project and add to an autoloader (if PSR autoloader or class-map is used).